# Joint spectral radius of $\sigma( \mathcal A)$ and $\rho(A) < 1 \forall A \in \mathcal A$

Tags: matrices, spectral-theory

Given $\mathcal A \subset R^{n \times n}$.

The joint spectral radius is by: $$\sigma( \mathcal A) = \limsup_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sup_{A \in \mathcal A^m}\rho(A),$$ where $\rho$ is the normal spectral radius an $\mathcal A^m = \{A_1 \cdot A_2\cdot \ldots \cdot A_m: A_i \in \mathcal A, i = 1, \ldots , m\}$.

I want to know, if it is possible to make a statement about the joint spectral radius $\sigma(\mathcal A)$, if we know that $\rho(A)<1 ~ \forall A \in \mathcal A$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Usually the joint spectral radii is defined as
$\sigma( \mathcal A) = \limsup_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sup_{A \in \mathcal A^m}\rho(A)^{1/m}$. I work with this definition next.

The following two matrices have spectral radius less then one, but the joint spectral radius is bigger then one.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}0  &  1  \\  0  &  0\end{bmatrix}$

$B=\begin{bmatrix}0  &  0  \\  1  &  0\end{bmatrix}$

$\rho(A)=0$, $\rho(B)=0$

but

$\sigma(\{A,B\})=1$ since $\rho(AB)^{1/2}=1$.

I suppose, it is impossible to deduce anything from the spectral radii of the matrices to their joint spectral radius, since there are unbounded matrices with spectral radius zero, e.g. $M=\begin{bmatrix}0  &  n  \\  0  &  0\end{bmatrix}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.